# jQuery $.load() - URL with data parameters

Tags: jquery

I want to load a page retrieved using a servlet call into a div.

Unfortunately, I want to pass huge data as a parameter for my servlet call and I cannot do this using the $.load function.

Can anybody suggest me a way to call my servlet through Post (I guess, I can send more data through Post) and still use $.load() to load it into my #div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) *defaults* to `GET`, but if you supply parameters as a data object, then it will do a `POST` instead of a `GET`. E.g.:

```
$("selector for target element").load('/path/to/your/page', {param1 : 'parameter'});
// Object as parameters ------------------------------------^
```